# Whateverorigin url incorrect when putting parameters in url

Tags: javascript, json

I am using Whateverorigin to get past the same-origin policy. I have made a request using `$.getJSON(url, callback)` and it worked fine. Now I want to send a request to an URL that includes parameters in the URL (e.g. `api.domain.com/get?key=value` ).

I am using the method `encodeURIComponent(url)` but it seems the parameters don't get through the request. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please mention the resultant response code or error message.

Comment: The API server returns an error message that says I did not include the parameters but I am sure I added them and encoded them.

Comment: can you check the actual outgoing request and confirm if the parameters are part of it, if you are using chrome press F12 and check networks tab to see the xhr request.

Comment: The parameters are actually part of it, and it is encoded. Or should I not encode the parameters?

Comment: Encode only the values of each parameter,i have once run into trouble by encoding the whole uri. After encoding & became %26 and = became %3D and server was returning 404.

Comment: Still no difference.

Comment: Same issue, getting 404 page